# PHP random DIV question

Tags: php, random

I am tried to use PHP to make DIV random positions. Here is my code.

```
<?php
function DIV1()
{
    $choose = array("left", "right");
    $rand_keys = array_rand($choose, 1);
    echo "<div class=position1 style=\"float:left;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:#00f;float:".$choose[$rand_keys].";border:1px solid #000;\"></div>";
}
function DIV2()
{
    $choose = array("left", "right");
    $rand_keys = array_rand($choose, 1);
    echo "<div class=position2 style=\"float:left;width:100px;height:200px;background-color:#f00;float:".$choose[$rand_keys].";border:1px solid #000;\"></div>";
}
function DIV3()
{
    $choose = array("left", "right");
    $rand_keys = array_rand($choose, 1);
    echo "<div class=position3 style=\"float:left;width:200px;height:100px;background-color:#ff0;float:".$choose[$rand_keys].";border:1px solid #000;\"></div>";
}

echo '<div id="display" style="width:1016px;height:1016px;background-color:#333;">';
    $count = Math.floor(rand()*25) +15;
    for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
    {
        echo DIV1();
        echo DIV2();
        echo DIV3();
    }

echo '</div>';
?>
```

My code can mixed divs position. But I have 2 questions.

1. How to control `15 pieces 100*100`, `10 pieces 100*200`, `5 pieces 200*100` divs mixed random display?
2. How to control the white space part? I want show all the divs in the display zone. `width:1016px;height:1016px;`, do not out of the `div#display`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on *do not out of the `div#display`*? You are merely floating the divs, they should never display *outside* of the parent.

Comment: @Jason McCreary, I thinks so, but in `chrome`, some divs will out of the `div#display` at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sizes = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
    array_push($sizes, $array(100,100));
}
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    array_push($sizes, $array(100,200));
}
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    array_push($sizes, $array(200,100));
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
   // Use array_rand() to pick out a random entry from $sizes and echo the div
}
```

About it not being out of the boundaries, just have it get a random top and left within those boundaries taking into account the width and height of the div.

Comment: `Function name must be a string` on line `array_push($sizes, $array(100,100); `...

Answer (score 0):

and you can use [rand()](http://tr.php.net/manual/tr/function.rand.php) function.

For example:

```
if (rand(0,10) == 1 )
{
    $sizes = 200;
}
```

rand() is Generate a random integer